# How to grant non-admin users to see full login history in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-data-masking

I am new to snowflake, As a DBA I got ACCOUNTADMIN access to start with. I have granted read access on information_schema.login_history and information_schema.query_history to our security application user, via  a role.

The user is able to login and query above views. However, the account is not able to see all rows when query above views. Only returns login history of that user, query history of that user. I tested it from my end, switching role from ACCOUNTADMIN to the read role I have created, and I see the same thing.

Can anyone tell me what privileges I need to grant the role, so anyone using that role can see all login history?

Comment: Welcome to Snowflake! Answer below

Answer (score 1):

There are two places where you can see login history -- in the Account Usage view or using the Information Schema table functions. The documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#differences-between-account-usage-and-information-schema) explains the differences.

After reviewing the differences, many customers will opt for giving non-admins access to Account_Usage views for auditing purposes. The grants needed for this are mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#enabling-account-usage-for-other-roles).

However, if you prefer giving the non-admin role access to the Information_Schema login_history table function, you may need to give a MONITOR grant on each desired user to this role as per the article [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Access-rights-to-view-login-history).

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant monitor privileges to said role:

```sql
grant monitor usage on account to role custom;
```

> This information can be accessed/viewed only by account administrators. To enable users who are not account administrators to access/view this information, Snowflake provides the global MONITOR USAGE privilege. Granting the MONITOR USAGE privilege to a role allows all users who are granted the role to access this historical/usage information.

> In addition, with this privilege, the SHOW DATABASES and SHOW WAREHOUSES commands return the lists of all databases and warehouses in the account, respectively, regardless of other privilege grants.

Ref: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-configure.html#enabling-non-account-administrators-to-monitor-usage-and-billing-history